# Puppeteer and angularjs html render issue

Tags: angularjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to prerender an webpage written in angularjs using puppeteer.
The stack of my application is MEAN (Mongo-Express-Angular-NodeJs).

Rendering logic is as follows:

```
var args = [
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--no-sandbox',
  ];


var getPageContent = async function getPageContent(request)
{
    var url = getUrl(request);
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, handleSIGINT: false, args: args});
    var page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    var html = await page.content();
    await browser.close();
    return html;
};
```

Everything works fine, and I do get the html of the page. However I get the html in the angular way. Like below:

```
<title> {{meta.title}} </title>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{meta.title}}">
<meta property="og:description" content="{{meta.description}}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{meta.imageSrc}}">
```

What I want is actual content of the page and not the {{}}.
Something like:

```
<title> My Page </title>
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page">
<meta property="og:description" content="Page about saving humanity">
<meta property="og:image" content="url_to_image">
```

I wonder if this is an issue with page.content() ? Or is there any other puppeteer API that would return the actual raw html of the page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.getmessages = async (page, selector, message) => {
const messages = [];
const bodyHandle = await page.$$(selector);
console.log(" table of messages length : ", bodyHandle.length);
const length = bodyHandle.length;
console.log(message + "switch ordre after load :\n")
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const element = bodyHandle[i];
    const content = await page.evaluate(body => body.textContent, element);
    console.log("message" + i + ": ", content + "\n");
    messages[i] = content;
}
return messages;}
```

Hello , I use the simular code with vue js and I get a html code with the right value created by vue , I hope that the code work for you ;)